What is the symbolism (τύποι) per 1 Cor. 10:4 of Christ being the Rock in Exodus and Numbers telling us about Christ?
In 1 Cor. 10:4 Paul told us that the rock Moses struck to get water symbolizes Christ; τύποι v6 and τυπικῶς v11 implies typology.

In Exodus 17:6 Moses struck the rock as commanded.  While in Numbers 20:8,11 God command Moses to tell/speak to the rock but Moes stuck it. What does striking and speaking to the rock symbolize?

The best I have heard is this. Moses represented the Law of God and his wrath for sin and so did his staff, which he used to bring plagues of death upon sinners. Christ was struck dead by this law, receiving the curse of the law, having all its wrath poured out on him.  Having been struck he splits open yielding living waters of righteousness and eternal life.  As with most symbols they are Christ in his death and resurrection.
I should add I don’t think there is amy nuance around the speaking / striking difference and that being asked to speak to the rock implied also the striking of it, as he was commanded to do previously and would be naturally interpreted to do again.

Ex. 17:6 “Behold, I will stand before you there on the rock at Horeb;
and you shall strike the rock, and water will come out of it, that the
people may drink.” And Moses did so in the sight of the elders of
Israel.

I am in the camp that both times represented the same symbol and striking was a necessary way to speak to it with his rod. Therefore God was not angry the Moses struck the rock but that he did twice in anger. However if a person did think there is meaning to speaking and this time, unlike last time and was only to speak and not use his rod, well, Moses brought the ‘word of the law’ and he had curses to speak to the enemies of God, through the Law, the Ten Commandments, with all its wrath against sin. Moses words were therefore, as a representative of Gods law and wrath, were meant to kill Christ dead for us. In other words the symbol is still the same.

In both cases, the Rock symbolized God, or in Paul's theology: Christ. A similar symbolic significance may be seen in the stone tablets that contained the Ten Commandments and the Temple (also made of stone) in the later history of Israel.  Water came from the rock. This was physical water, foreshadowing the "water of life" often mentioned in the New Testament
Striking and speaking seem to have the same significance if they are done with an attitude of sanctification. The problem in Numbers is that Moses struck the rock in anger against the people, rather than to uplift God. Also, he struck it twice rather than once. Comparing the texts:
Ex. 17

Moses cried out to the Lord, “What shall I do with this people? A
little more and they will stone me!” 5 The Lord answered Moses: Go on
ahead of the people, and take along with you some of the elders of
Israel, holding in your hand, as you go, the staff with which you
struck the Nile. 6 I will be standing there in front of you on the
rock in Horeb. Strike the rock, and the water will flow from it for
the people to drink. Moses did this, in the sight of the elders of
Israel.

Num. 20

the Lord said to Moses: 8 Take the staff and assemble the community,
you and Aaron your brother, and in their presence command the rock to
yield its waters. Thereby you will bring forth water from the rock for
them, and supply the community and their livestock with water. 9 So
Moses took the staff from its place before the Lord, as he was
ordered. 10 Then Moses and Aaron gathered the assembly in front of the
rock, where he said to them, “Just listen, you rebels! Are we to
produce water for you out of this rock?” 11 Then, raising his hand,
Moses struck the rock twice with his staff, and water came out in
abundance, and the community and their livestock drank. 12 But the
Lord said to Moses and Aaron: Because you did not have confidence in
me, to acknowledge my holiness before the Israelites, therefore you
shall not lead this assembly into the land I have given them.

Important differences in the two scenes:

In Ex. 17 Moses does not let his anger against the people get the best of him, while in Num. 20 he moves to strikes the rock in anger rather than to uplift God in the eyes of the people.

In Exodus he is commanded to strike the rock but in Numbers he is commanded to speak to it. Some commentators see this as the key difference, but in my opinion it is his attitude that is the crucial point. If Moses had struck the rock once in Numbers, but had done it to uplift God rather than as an expression of anger against the people, things might have gone differently.

The second strike may thus be crucial. Supposing the rock symbolized Christ in both cases: striking it once sanctified God and expressed confidence in God's power, but striking it the second time expressed faithlessness and thus defiled the rock rather than sanctifying God.


Conclusion: The stone tablets containing the Ten Commandments, the rock, and even the later Temple were all objects of stone that symbolized God's word or his presence. The leader - be it a prophet, the high priest, or any spiritual leader - needs to lift up these sacred objects in the eyes of the people and thus provide spiritual sustenance. Contemporary Christians may take comfort in the idea that "they drank from a spiritual rock that followed them, and the rock was the Christ." As Moses was to show God's holiness in regard to the rock, Christians are to acknowledge Christ's holiness. The waters of life will flow in abundance as a result.


What does striking and speaking to the rock symbolize?

Clearly (from a Christian perspective) the rock itself symbolized Christ, striking the rock symbolized his execution, and the water symbolized God's holy spirit's being made available to save people's lives.
(Similarly, the stone tablets that were broken and then remade also symbolize Christ.)
Speaking to the rock certainly had great significance, but it doesn't necessarily have any symbolic meaning.
In Exodus:

God said: "Strike the rock".
"Moses struck the rock".

So Moses literally did what was asked.
But Numbers provides an additional detail:

God said: "As the people watch, speak to the rock over there, and it will pour out its water.".
Moses told the Israelites: "Hear now, ye rebels; must we [Moses and Aaron] fetch you water out of this rock?".
After providing the water, God reprimanded Moses: "Because you did not trust me enough to demonstrate my holiness to the people of Israel".

While Moses struck the rock as required, he did not present the miracle in the way he was supposed to, as a demonstration of God's power and his ability and desire to save the people.
The Israelites were given the wrong message.
Rather than saying something like "In the name of the LORD, I command you to produce water!",
Moses made it look like he personally caused the water to appear by striking the rock, as if he himself was a magician.
If there is any symbolic meaning to how Moses spoke, perhaps it is that salvation must be asked for, and perhaps it applies to today's clergy and religious leaders, who can sometimes perform their duties as if through their own power and not merely as God's agents.
